# Table row hover to show toolbar

Tags: html, jquery

I'm facing some problems with my HTML code. I am trying to display a button toolbar at the row when user hover over the row in a table. Below is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    var $divOverlay = $('#DivToShow');
        $('#grid').on("mouseover", "tbody > tr", function ()
        {
            var bottomWidth = $(this).css('width');
            var bottomHeight = $(this).css('height');
            var rowPos = $(this).position();
            bottomTop = $(this).offset().top;
            bottomLeft = rowPos.left;
            $divOverlay.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: bottomTop,
                //left: bottomLeft,

                height: bottomHeight
            });
            $divOverlay.show();
        });
$('#resultGrid').on("mouseleave", "tbody > tr", function ()
        {
            $divOverlay.hide();
        });
        $divOverlay.mouseleave(function ()
        {
            $divOverlay.hide();
        });
});
```

```css
#DivToShow {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    right:0;
    padding-right:10px;
}
tr:hover {
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
<table id="grid" width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td>d</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>e</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id="DivToShow" >
  <button>Edit</button> &nbsp;
  <button>Dup</button>&nbsp;
  <button>Delete</button>
</div>
```

And here is some of the things that I want to achieve:

1. Currently the table row gets highlighted when user mouse over it. I would like to keep the row highlighted when user hover on the button toolbar section too.
2. When user mouse leave the row, the button toolbar should disappear. Now it will only disappear when the user got mouse over the button toolbar section.
3. Is there anyway that I can get the current row data when I click on the edit button?

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi,when do you need to show that toolbar ? Currently that code is under mouseover and your second point which you need to achieve is not clear ..? can you elaborate

Comment: Did you get your desired result? Could you please update it here because I am stuck in same situation? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i believe what you are trying to accomplish can easily be done with css,, except the clickevent part

here is the easiest way to do this, i hope this is what wanted

```js
function edit(value){
  console.log(value);
}
function dup(value){
  console.log(value);
}
function remove(value){
  console.log(value);
}
```

```css
#DivToShow {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: right;
}
td {
  position: relative;
}
tr:hover {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}
tr:hover #DivToShow{
  display:block
}
```

```html
<table id="grid" width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a
          <div id="DivToShow" >
            <button onClick="edit('a')">Edit</button>
            <button onClick="dup('a')">Dup</button>
            <button onClick="remove('a')">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b
          <div id="DivToShow" >
            <button onClick="edit('b')">Edit</button>
            <button onClick="dup('b')">Dup</button>
            <button onClick="remove('b')">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>c
          <div id="DivToShow" >
            <button onClick="edit('c')">Edit</button>
            <button onClick="dup('c')">Dup</button>
            <button onClick="remove('c')">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td>d</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>d
          <div id="DivToShow" >
            <button onClick="edit('d')">Edit</button>
            <button onClick="dup('d')">Dup</button>
            <button onClick="remove('d')">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>e
          <div id="DivToShow" >
            <button onClick="edit('e')">Edit</button>
            <button onClick="dup('e')">Dup</button>
            <button onClick="delete('e')">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have updated my code..For my table, it could be a lot of column inside and the horizontal scrollbar might appear. So I would like the button toolbar to appear at the row end but not the last column.. its my bad for not mention this but thanks for the answer.. :)